# predict on test data in random forest survival analysis

Tags: r, random-forest, survival-analysis

I'm using predict on real data cohort on a model trained by package randomForestSRC in R. The real data cohort has missing values whereas the training set that produced the model does not have missing values.

```
pred_cohort <- predict(model, cohort,na.action = "na.impute")
```

Since the cohort is a small set (only 8 observation) the number of levels of the factors are fewer than in the training set produced the model. I realize now by a coincidence that if I set the levels of the real data cohort to be the levels of the model (se code example below) I get different answers of the prediction than if I do not. why is that?

```
levels(cohort$var1)<levels(model$xvar$var1)
```

I also realize that the imputed value for the missing cells are different if I force the levels of the real data to be the levels of the model (according to the code above) then if I leave the levels as is.

The question is if this is a bug? if not, which way to prefer? And why to prefer that option?

Comment: Please add a reproducible example, and further elaborate on the problem. What do you mean by different answers? How big is the training dataset etc?

Comment: I found the problem, when changing levels according to above it is not only levels that changes but also the values within the dataframe. That is why I got different results. Instead, to just fix the levels one should type "cohort[,'var1'] <- factor(cohort[,'var1'],levels=levels(model$xvar[,'var1']))